# XML validation: is it necessary to bind the elements to a namespace?

Tags: xml, xsd-validation

I'm trying to validate a client XML using a Schema they have sent. Schematically it looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8">
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
           xmlns="http://www.client.com"
           targetNamespace="http://www.client.com"
           elementFormDefault="qualified"
           attributeFormDefault="unqualified"
           version="0.1">

<xs:element name="root">
  <xs:complexType>
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element ref="Parent" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>

<xs:element name="Parent">
  <xs:complexType>
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="Child1" type="xs:string"/>
      <xs:element name="Child2" type="xs:string" nillable="true"/>
      <xs:element name="Child3" type="xs:string"/>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>

</xs:schema>
```

An example of the XML I'd like to validate would be

```
<Parent>
  <Child1>Entry</Child1>
  <Child2 xsi:nil="true"/>
  <Child3>Entry</Child3>
</Parent>
```

My question is this: is the XML above actually well-formed? My (poor) understanding of XML makes me think that a namespace is required for the 'xsi' tag, and indeed when we validate this is the error we get (The tag 'xsi' is not bound to any namespace). Changing the XML to look like:

```
<Parent xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <Child1>Entry</Child1>
  <Child2 xsi:nil="true"/>
  <Child3>Entry</Child3>
</Parent>
```

fixes problems on our end and makes more sense to me. However the client have said the original XML validates in XMLSpy and VisualStudio so maybe I'm missing something?

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks very much!

Comment: <Child2 xsi:nil="true" /> tag was not closed.

Comment: Good spot! Unfortunately my fault for copying badly though. Thanks.

Comment: I have edited your title to reflect your _real_ question: '_So my question is really pointing to the lack of binding of the xsi tag: is this necessary, and if it is, why is XMLSpy apparently validating it anyway?_'

Answer (score 0):

There is a difference between well-formed XML and valid XML. Your example is well-formed but it is not valid. Validity comes into picture if you have a schema defined.

Read the below two articles

1. http://dli.grainger.uiuc.edu/publications/xmltutorial/xml/tsld005.htm
2. [Referencing XSD Schemas in Documents](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms757863%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Comment: Thanks for the references Pangea. I certainly agree that my question should have been one of validity and not well-formedness. Beyond this: we get no issues when the second example above is implemented (i.e. the document does not explicitly reference the XSD, but the xsi namespace is bound). We have checked that legitimate validation is occuring by purposely misplacing an xml tag and checking that the system is catching it - it does. So my question is really pointing to the lack of binding of the xsi tag: is this necessary, and if it is, why is XMLSpy apparently validating it anyway?

Answer (score 0):

## Is it necessary to bind the elements to a namespace?

Elements are always bound to a '[namespace name](http://www.w3.org/TR/xml-names/#dt-NSName)'. If no URI has been provided for the namespace, then the 'namespace name' has no value. You can then use the noNamespaceSchemaLocation attribute to define the element type.

For instance, if your xml matched the target namespace, you would write

```xml
<Parent xmlns="http://www.client.com" 
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.client.com client.xsd">
...
</Parent>

<!--
Remarks:
(Line 1) default namespace (when using no prefix) = "http://www.client.com"
(Line 3) provided that `client.xsd` is the correct client schema location.
-->
```

In this case, both `Parent` and `Child` elements belong to the "http://www.client.com" namespace and the validator knows against what it have to validate the xml.

If your schema didn't declare the `targetNamespace="http://www.client.com"`, then to validate against your schema you'd need to write:

```xml
<Parent xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="http://www.client.com client.xsd">
...
</Parent>
```

In this case, both `Parent` and `Child` belong to the "no value" namespace, so that they would be validated against the "no-targetNamespaced" schema.

## Is it necessary to bind prefixes to namespaces?

For your examples, I guess this is what you are asking for. From the [specs](http://www.w3.org/TR/xml-names/#NT-Prefix):

> The Prefix provides the namespace prefix part of the qualified name, and *MUST* be associated with a namespace URI reference in a namespace declaration.

So yes, you have to bind them.

Comment: I guess you also grasp the meaning of `<Child2 xsi:nil="true"/>` where you are defining a `noNamespaceSchemaLocation:Parent` element and a `xsi:nil` attribute that belong to different document definition types?

Comment: Regarding '_why is XMLSpy apparently validating it anyway?_' I guess XMLSpy has its own more condescending rules, and it either ignores the `xsi:nil` for which no namespace name has been defined; or uses its default `xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"` binding.